# Как дождаться завершения нескольких последовательных промисов?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Передо мной стоит задача выполнить несколько асинхронных процессов в angularjs ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНО. Их количество заранее не известно. 
Как пример: в процедуру передается путь и нужно создать все папки последовательно, т.к. следующую папку можно создать только в предыдущей. При этом нужно дождаться завершения.
Я сделал это через рекурсивный вызов `_manager`, процедура отрабатывает, но о завершении в start не сообщает.

```
.factory('TEST_F', function ($timeout, $q) {

    var isStop = false;
    var stop = function () {
      isStop = true;
      console.log('stop loop');
    };

    var start = function () {
      console.log('start loop');
      isStop = false;
      var i = 0;
      _manager(i)
        .then(function (data) {
          console.log('---> resolve, i = ' + data.i);
        }, function (data) {
          console.log('---> reject, i = ' + data.i);
        });
    };

    var _manager = function (i) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      _doer()
        .then(function (data) {
          i++;
          console.log('isStop = ' + isStop, 'i = ' + i);
          if (data.state === 'ok' && !isStop) {
            //deferred.resolve({state: 'ok', i: i});
            return _manager(i);
          } else {
            deferred.reject({state: 'error', i: i});
            return {state: 'error', i: i};
          }
        }, function (data) {
          deferred.reject({state: 'error', i: i});
          return {state: 'error', i: i};
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    };

    var _doer = function () {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $timeout(function () {
        console.log('loop');
      }, 2000)
        .then(function (data) {
          console.log('+2 sec');
          deferred.resolve({state: 'ok'});
        })
      ;
      return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
      stop: stop,
      start: start
    }
  })
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать последовательное выполнение асинхронных процедур?

Comment: А почему в `_manager` строка `deferred.resolve({state: 'ok', i: i});` закомментирована?

Comment: Потому, что обещание вернет следующая строка.

Comment: А что толку обещать, если нигде не выполнять (`.resolve()`) свои обещания? В таком случае вам нужно передавать объект `deferred` в рекурсивные  вызовы функции и делать `.resolve()` в последнем из них. `return` внутри функции в `.then()` бесполезен.

Comment: Если же, судя по коду, последний `_manager()` должен всегда делать `.reject()`, то тогда проблема в том, что `.reject()` делается для `deferred` из последнего `_manager()`, а не из первого, в то время как `start()` ждёт результат от первого `deferred`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Regent, учел Ваши подсказки и переписал _manager.

```
var _manager = function (i) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
```

`_doer(i)
    .then(function (data) {
      i++;
      console.log('isStop = ' + isStop, 'i = ' + i);
      if (data.state === 'ok' && !isStop && i < 7) { // доп. условие остановки
        //deferred.resolve({state: 'ok', i: i});
        return _manager(i);
      } else {
        //deferred.resolve({state: 'end', i: data.i});
        return {state: 'end', i: data.i};
      }
    }, function (data) {
      //deferred.reject({state: 'error', i: data.i});
      return {state: 'error', i: data.i};
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      if(data.state === 'ok') {
        deferred.resolve({state: 'ok', i: data.i});
      } else if (data.state === 'end') {
        deferred.resolve({state: 'end', i: data.i});
      } else {
        deferred.resolve({state: 'error', i: data.i});
      }
    })
  ;

  return deferred.promise;
};`

Теперь все работает так, как мне нужно. Но мне кажется, что это можно написать как-то короче.

Comment: Боль и страдания, особенно с `$q`, но я всё же заставил [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ajnndrq/1/) работать. Сейчас попробую упростить код.

Comment: @Regent, я в начале поста написал, что мне нужно дождаться последовательного исполнения асинхронных запросов, когда их количество заранее не известно. $timeout() использован для их имитации. Такая необходимость возникла при создании подпапок на мобильном устройстве (ionic) когда я не знаю заранее глубину вложенности и создаю весь путь. Или когда нужно один за другим отправить файлы на сервер. Конечно, можно было использовать $q.all([]), но в конкретно моем случае это было не совсем то, что мне было нужно.

Comment: Да, извините, пока ковырялся с кодом, уже и забыл про что был вопрос... В общем, никакого радикального упрощения кода с тем же функционалом я так и не нашел. Из-за необходимости использования `Promise` и разных ответов в разных ситуациях код примерно так и выглядит.

Comment: @Regent, благодарю Вас!

Comment: На здоровье. Хотя, по сути, почти и не за что. Так как ваш ответ является решением вопроса, вы можете отметить его как правильный.

Comment: @Regent, я пытался. Но еще не отработал таймер ожидания ))

Answer (score 0):

У вас нет условия остановки. Поскольку i может расти сколь угодно долго - ничего и не получается.

Comment: Условие остановки - вызов метода `.stop()` где-то во внешнем коде.